# Python mmap.move()

Tags: python, linux, file-io, mmap

When executing `mmap.move()` is the entire file after the 'dest' point rewritten?

If I have a large file, say over a gig, and I want to remove just the first line (maybe 70 bytes?), I could do something like `mmap.move(0, 70, <size - 70>)` and truncate the last 70 bytes off the end of the file if needed.  When doing this, does the entire file (minus the 70 bytes I overwrote) get completely read and written back to disk?

If so, is there any way to delete from the start of a file without having to re-write the entire thing?

Comment: Removing data from the start of a file *always* requires rewriting, there is no way around that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought so- just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical filesystems have no feature like "truncate at the beginning of a file," but you can imagine creating a file *format* with such a feature.  For example, if your original file is like this:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

And you want to remove AB:

```
CDEFGHIJKL
```

But you don't want to shuffle all the data, so settle for this:

```
KLCDEFGHIJ
```

To support just this, all you need is an index to where the file "starts" so you can treat it like a circular buffer.  In this case, the index would begin at 0, and after deleting AB it would be 2, and you would copy only the amount of data being deleted (so the operation would be O(m) instead of O(n), where m is the amount deleted and n the total size).

As for where and how to store the bookkeeping information, that depends on what the native file format is, and which filesystem you're using.  You could even store it in a separate metadata system like a database, depending on your needs.